# Not able to find out the number of Sentences in a File

Tags: java, file

I am writing a code to find out the number of sentences in a file.
My code is as :

```
 try{
    int count =0;

FileInputStream f1i = new FileInputStream(s);
Scanner sc = new Scanner(f1i);
    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        String g = sc.nextLine();
 if(g.indexOf(".")!= -1)
     count++;
 sc.nextLine();

}
System.out.println("The number of sentences are :"+count);
}
catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        }
```

I guess my logic is right to check for the number of periods. I wrote the above code which i think is right but it displays a `javautilNoElementfound : No line found`exception . I tried some other logics but this one was the best understandable. But i am stuck here. I used google on that exception and it says that it is thrown when we iterate over something that has no element.But my file contains data. Is there some way this exception could have made way?? Or is there some other error? Hints are appreciated ! Thanks

Comment: You are calling `sc.nextLine()` two times inside the `while` loop that is why the error occurs.

Comment: Also your logic doesn't account for cases when there are 2 sentences on the same line.

Comment: Ok, if that is it .Then, how do i get the Line in a string with moving on to next line so as to keep the while working ?? Any help ?? And why would it not work for two sentences in a line ? The string would search for it, won't it ? @Titus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `sc.nextLine()` two times inside the `while` loop that is why the error occurs.
Also your logic doesn't account for cases when there are 2 sentences on the same line.
You can try something like this:
`int sentencesPerLine = g.split(".").length;`

The loop should be:

```
while(sc.hasNextLine()){
    String g = sc.nextLine();
    if(g.indexOf('.')!= -1){//check if the line contains a '.' character
        count += g.split("\\.").length; // split the line into an array of Strings using '.' as a delimiter
    }
}
```

In the [split(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method I'm using `"\\."` instead of `"."` because `.` is a regex element and needs to be escaped.

Comment: Also the logic does not account for periods that are not part of a sentence.  You might want to use ". " instead of ".".  Since every sentence has a space after a period.

Comment: @Jose Martinez, That is a good suggestion, he can edit the code further based on his requirements.

Comment: @Titus I ran the code with your loop and ". " instead of "." . But that displays the wrong number of sentences. I have 5 sentences scattered over in a file and it displays 10.. ???

Comment: @Kirty Bhushan That is because the `split(...)` method expects a regular expression as an argument. I've edited my answer, try it now.

Comment: Now it worked if i use the loop with split same as yours and indexOf(".") instead of indexOf(". "). With the latter it shows less number of sentences than present... ??

Comment: Thanks , i got it ! Sorted it myself. I appreciate the help.